# cannot resolve symbol 'setTypeface'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-typeface

```
// Font path
String fontPath = "fonts/jcc.ttf";

// text view label
TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ghost);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

// Applying font
txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

In Android Studio it comes up with an error, "Cannot resolve symbol 'setTypeface'" and "Unknown class: 'tf'". I do not know why, I defined 'tf' and I have looked at many tutorial's that use setTypeface. 
Please Help!

Edit, here is a screenshot, I am using this exact code and my fonts are under 'assets/font/jcc.tf'.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRTbY.png 
Sorry do not have enough reputation to post images :(

Comment: Have you imported `android.graphics.Typeface` class ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri, Yes android.graphics.Typeface is imported.

Comment: Where are you placed your font? in "assets/fonts/"? I can't find the error there, so it should be a little mistake like this one. Please, give us more information :)

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using, and are there no other errors or warnings displayed?

Comment: The font is under 'assets/fonts' (check the edit up top :P) and the only other warning is that there is an unused variable 'button'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error I found the solution!

My code was after the onCreate method, once I placed it inside all the errors went away!

The code with errors:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    // Font path
    String fontPath = "fonts/SECRCODE.ttf";

    // text view label
    TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.java1);

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

The code without errors (notice the code is now inside onCreate method):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Font path
    String fontPath = "fonts/SECRCODE.ttf";

    // text view label
    TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.java1);

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

If anyone could explain why this works it would help greatly! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need to set the font (typeface) in the onCreate method is because your Java code in the onCreate method is automatically executed when an activity is loaded. Without putting it inside the onCreate() method there is no reference/call to execute your code.